# Can't use var or let outside function in Angular CLI

Tags: angular

In my Angular CLI components, I get an error when defining a variable as a 'var' or 'let' outside of a function. I also get an error using the keyword 'function'. If I declare just by name it's fine. For instance in this stripped down component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {}

  var aaa = '1';       // nope
  let bbb = '2';       // nope
  ccc = '3';           // ok

  method1(){           // ok
    let ddd = '4';     // ok
  }

  function method2(){  // nope

  }

}
```

For aaa, bbb, and method2 it is throwing the error: "[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect it is a configuration problem with my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare properties of the class as either `public` or `private`.

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {}

  public aaa = '1';       
  private bbb = '2';    
  ccc = '3';           // <-- by default this is public

  method1(){           // ok
    let ddd = '4';     // ok
  }

  private method1(){  // Available only within the class

  }

  public method2(){  // Accessible outside the class

  }

}
```

Comment: No problem. He is a quick draw, I thought I was on that right away. Happy to help anyways! :)

Comment: To be fair, he beat me by one minute, with an incomplete answer. And given my reputation vs his, I don't mind if you mark his answer as the correct one @EricSoyke !

Comment: As you wish @trichetriche !

Comment: Hey cool! Thank you both, you didn't have to, but that was a kind gesture.

Answer (score 2):

Because your features (component, service, pipe, etc) are classes.

In classes, you define properties with accessors, not scoped variables.

This will work

```
export class MyComponent {
  private x;
  public y;
  protected z;

  public doSmth() {
    const b = 'B';
    return b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well get back to it, because typescript is very similar to Java !